# How do you get parcel to open in a specific browser of my choice?

Tags: parceljs

My parcel bundler opens up in default MS edge but i want it open local host in firefox.

Comment: Did the answers solve your problem?

Comment: @MarioG8 Yes. worked perfectly!

Comment: So you can mark my answer  as solving your question ;-) Best regards !

Comment: @MarioG8 Hey, thank you so much for noticing. I absolutely missed for reason unknown. Personal bug I guess.

Comment: Best regards ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work on Win10 and Linux Ubuntu 20.04. If you have `parcel` installed globally

In your root project folder enter the command(terminal)

```
 parcel --open firefox index.html
```

**OR**

If you have `parcel` installed locally than change your **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel --open firefox index.html",
    "prod": "parcel build index.html"
  },
```

And hit in terminal `npm run dev`
You are done ! :-) Good Luck and Best regards;-)

Comment: Yes!! This was it! Thank you so much man!

Comment: @Eddie  You're welcome ! Glad to help You ;-) Best regards !